Problem Training YOLOv5 Model with SageMaker Using S3 Bucket Data
I'm trying to training yolov5 model with sagemaker using s3 bucket data.
The total size of the training data stored in S3 exceeds 100 GB, so I am trying to use Pipe mode to load the data.
the main code is here:
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch
from sagemaker.inputs import TrainingInput

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()

bucket = 'sdij-ml'
prefix = 'yolov5-training'

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

estimator = PyTorch(
    entry_point='train.py',
    source_dir='/root/yolov5',
    role=role,
    framework_version='2.2',
    py_version='py310',
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',
    hyperparameters={
        'img': 960,
        'batch': 32,
        'epochs': 100,
        'data': 'data.yaml',
        'device': 0,
        'weights': 'yolov5l.pt',
        'project': '/opt/ml/model',
        'name': 'SDIJ_Textbook'
    }
)

train_input = TrainingInput(
    f's3://{bucket}/textbook/Dataset/train/',
    distribution='FullyReplicated',
    content_type='application/x-image',
    s3_data_type='S3Prefix',
    input_mode='Pipe'
)

val_input = TrainingInput(
    f's3://{bucket}/textbook/Dataset/valid/',
    distribution='FullyReplicated',
    content_type='application/x-image', 
    s3_data_type='S3Prefix',
    input_mode='Pipe'
)

estimator.fit({'train': train_input, 'val': val_input})

and the data.yaml file is here :
names:
- Problem
- Problem_no
- Meta_data
- Problem_source
- Page_num
- Theme
- Solution_no
- Solution
- Solution_broken
- Problem_broken

nc: 10

train: /opt/ml/input/data/train
val: /opt/ml/input/data/val
test: /opt/ml/input/data/test

The error appears as follows. I believe the dataset downloaded from S3 is not being recognized properly. Which part of the code might be causing this issue?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ml/code/train.py", line 852, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "/opt/ml/code/train.py", line 627, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "/opt/ml/code/train.py", line 176, in train
    data_dict = data_dict or check_dataset(data)  # check if None
  File "/opt/ml/code/utils/general.py", line 563, in check_dataset
    raise Exception("Dataset not found ❌")
Exception: Dataset not found ❌
2024-07-02 18:20:27,719 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Waiting for the process to finish and give a return code.
2024-07-02 18:20:27,719 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Done waiting for a return code. Received 1 from exiting process.
2024-07-02 18:20:27,719 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    Reporting training FAILURE
2024-07-02 18:20:27,720 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 1
ErrorMessage "raise Exception("Dataset not found ❌")
 Exception: Dataset not found ❌"
Command "/opt/conda/bin/python3.10 train.py --batch 32 --data data.yaml --device 0 --epochs 100 --img 960 --name SDIJ_Textbook --project /opt/ml/model --weights yolov5l.pt"
2024-07-02 18:20:27,720 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    Encountered exit_code 1

2024-07-02 18:20:36 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2024-07-02 18:20:45 Failed - Training job failed

